# kivy custom widget how to access attributes set using kvlang

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to implement an html style SelectBox widget in kivy using the `kivy.uix.DropDown`.
In the actual application I want to use it like this using kvlang:

```
        SelectBox:
            id: appeui
            label: "Select an application"
            SelectOption:
                label: 'Option 1'
                value: 1
            SelectOption:
                label: 'Option 2'
                value: 2
            SelectOption:
                label: 'Option 3'
                value: 3
```

To implement this widget, I have defined the SelectBox and SelectOption below. In the constructor of the `SelectBox` I am checking properties on the SelectBox, that I am expecting to be set in kvlang. One is the label which is then used as the label for the button. And I am also checking the children of the `SelectBox`  and moving all of them (of type `SelecOption`) to the `DropDown`. The problem I am encountering is that in the constructor of SelectBox, there is no label argument, and no children yet either.

I think the `SelectBox` instantiation already happens before the kvlang stuff is read. So during instantiation the attributes defined in kvlang for `SelectBox` and also its children aren't known yet.
Is there any other function that gets called after the widget is actually built by kvlang? Or any other way I can actually act upon the way the widget was defined in kvlang?

```
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class SelectOption(Label):
    def __init__(self,
                 *args,
                 label='option',
                 value=None,
                 background_color=Color(rgba=(1, 1, 1, 1)),
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label = label
        self.value = value
        self.background_color = background_color
        self.bind(on_touch_down=self.select)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(self.background_color)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

    def select(self, *args):
        self.parent.select(self.value)


class SelectBox(Widget):
    def __init__(self, label='Select an option', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        self.value = None
        self.button = Button(text=label)
        self.add_widget(self.button)
        self.button.id = 'dropdown_label'
        self.button.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.button.height = '32dp'
        self.button.bind(on_release=self.openDropDown)
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=self.set_value)

        for child in self.children:
            if isinstance(child, SelectOption):
                self.dropdown.add_widget(child)
                self.remove_widget(child)

    def openDropDown(self, *args):
        self.dropdown.open(self.button)

    def set_value(self, instance, value):
        self.ids.dropdown_label.text = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am getting somewhere. The issue here is to just not use the constructor, but use events instead. You can define properties on the SelectBox and use events to intercept changes in that property. When the property is defined in kvlang, this will trigger the event. So in my case I could do this:

```
class SelectBox(StackLayout, EventDispatcher):
    label = StringProperty('Select an option')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        self.value = None
        self.button = Button(text=self.label)
        self.button.id = 'dropdown_label'
        self.add_widget(self.button)
        self.button.bind(on_release=self.openDropDown)
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=self.set_value)

    def on_label(self, instance, value):
        print("Label changed")
        self.button.text = value

    def add_widget(self, child):
        print(f"Adding widget {child}")

        if isinstance(child, SelectOption):
            self.dropdown.add_widget(child)
        else:
            super().add_widget(child)

    def openDropDown(self, *args):
        print("Opening dropdown")
        self.dropdown.open(self.button)

    def set_value(self, instance, value):
        self.ids.dropdown_label.text = value
```

The `on_label` event gets called as soon as the label property is set in kvlang, and then I just change the button text.

For the child widgets, I am doing something similar by intercepting `add_widget`. If its a `SelectOption`, then add it to the dropdown instead of adding it to the `SelectBox`.

There are still issues with this code, but they are not directly related to this question.